# Creating a class with and image in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to create my own class in corona based on [this example](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/29/tutorial-modular-classes-in-corona/)
It looks like:

```
local car={};
local car_mt = { __index=car };
function car.new()
    local ncar=
    {
        img=display:newImage("test_car.png");
    }
    return setmetatable(ncar,car_mt);
end
return car;
```

And it's called at level by this:

```
local pcar=require("car")
...
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    physics.start();
    local car1=pcar.new();

end
```

The image exists in the same folder, but i get:

> bad argument #-2 to newImage (Proxy expected, got nil)

I saw some similar issues in the Net, and it seems to me that `newImage()` doesn't know where to place a picture. But how can I say it if the class it made to be used for any stage?

Comment: Try calling it as `pcar:new();`

Comment: The same error. Nothing changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, the error is because you're calling `newImage` function as:

```
display:newImage( "test_car.png" )
```

which is the wrong syntax. The above statement actually means:

```
display.newImage( display, "test_car.png" )
```

which, obviously is wrong.

The correct method would be:

```
display.newImage( "test_car.png" )
```

Read more about the [corona](/questions/tagged/corona) API [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html).